# MIPS assembly - How to make sure MIPS is printing '4' from an array as a '4' and not EOT( end of transmission)

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a MIPS code that gathers an input from a user and converts it into a different string with a key inside an array.
The problem is that the keys are just numbers 2,3,4... but when mips reads this, it assumes its the Dec code for what it means in ascii. How do I make sure the actual number 4 is printed when it reads '$' (Key attached at code below)

```
    .data
    
inBuf:      .space  80      # input line
outBuf:         .space  80      # char types for the input line
prompt: .asciiz "Enter a new input line. \n”
.data
tabChar:    
    .word   0x09, 6     # tab
    .word   0x0a, 6     # LF
    .word   ' ', 6
    .word   '#', 5
    .word   '$', 4
    .word   '(', 4 
    .word   ')', 4 
    .word   '*', 3 
    .word   '+', 3 
    .word   ',', 4 
    .word   '-', 3 
    .word   '.', 4 
    .word   '/', 3 
    .word   '0', 1
    .word   '1', 1 
    .word   '2', 1 
    .word   '3', 1 
    .word   '4', 1 
    .word   '5', 1 
    .word   '6', 1 
    .word   '7', 1 
    .word   '8', 1 
    .word   '9', 1 
    .word   ':', 4 
    .word   'A', 2
    .word   'B', 2 
    .word   'C', 2 
    .word   'D', 2 
    .word   'E', 2 
    .word   'F', 2 
    .word   'G', 2 
    .word   'H', 2 
    .word   'I', 2 
    .word   'J', 2 
    .word   'K', 2
    .word   'L', 2 
    .word   'M', 2 
    .word   'N', 2 
    .word   'O', 2 
    .word   'P', 2 
    .word   'Q', 2 
    .word   'R', 2 
    .word   'S', 2 
    .word   'T', 2 
    .word   'U', 2
    .word   'V', 2 
    .word   'W', 2 
    .word   'X', 2 
    .word   'Y', 2
    .word   'Z', 2
    .word   'a', 2 
    .word   'b', 2 
    .word   'c', 2 
    .word   'd', 2 
    .word   'e', 2 
    .word   'f', 2 
    .word   'g', 2 
    .word   'h', 2 
    .word   'i', 2 
    .word   'j', 2 
    .word   'k', 2
    .word   'l', 2 
    .word   'm', 2 
    .word   'n', 2 
    .word   'o', 2 
    .word   'p', 2 
    .word   'q', 2 
    .word   'r', 2 
    .word   's', 2 
    .word   't', 2 
    .word   'u', 2
    .word   'v', 2 
    .word   'w', 2 
    .word   'x', 2 
    .word   'y', 2
    .word   'z', 2
    .word   0x5c, -1        # if you ‘\’ as the end-of-table symbol


.text
getline:
la  $a0, prompt     # Prompt to enter a new line
li  $v0, 4
syscall

la  $a0, inBuf      # read a new line
li  $a1, 80 
li  $v0, 8
syscall

linearSearch:
li $t0, 0 #load 0 into index

j linearLoop

linearLoop:
li $t4, 0 #load 0 into inner index
lb $a0, inBuf($t0) #load first byte from input
j linearLoopTab


linearLoopTab:
lb $a1, tabChar($t4) #load first byte from tabchar
beq $a1, $a0, found #compares input byte to tab byte, if similar jump to found
li $t2, '#' #makes t2 '#'
beq $a0, $t2, exit #if current input byte is '#', exit
addiu $t4, $t4, 8 #add index
j linearLoopTab #loop back

found:
addi $t4,$t4,4 #selects correct pos for encrypted message
lb $a2, tabChar($t4) #load first byte from input
subi $t4,$t4,4 #reverting pos


sb $a2, outBuf($t0) #store it into outbuff at index pos
addi $t0, $t0, 1 #add index
j linearLoop


exit:
la $a0, outBuf
li $v0, 4         #prints and leaves
syscall
la $a0,inBuf
jal clear
la $a0,outBuf
jal clear
li $v0, 10 #exit command
syscall

clear:
    li    $t0, 0
```

I already tried to change the "li $v0, 4         #prints and leaves"
to system code 1 for integer. That results in a very strange number to be printed (268501072)
I am unsure why that happens

Comment: It's weird that you have an array of `.word` elements when you only have characters and small integers.  If you used `.byte`, it would only take 1/4 of the space.  (And the code would be just as simple, like `lb $a2, tabChar+1 ($t4)` instead of `lb $a2, tabChar+4 ($t4)`.)

Comment: There's no need to increment `$t4` and then decrement, just use the 16-bit offset in the addressing mode which is apparently enough to hold the whole symbol address.  (Maybe MARS is supporting that as a pseudo-instruction, or you have it configured to put your data section in the low 64KiB).  If you did want to `addiu` instead of using the addressing mode, you should do it into a different temporary register so you don't have to decrement again.  i.e. implement `arr[t4+1]` instead of `t4++; arr[t4];  t4--;`.  MIPS is a 3-operand ISA with tons of registers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, just added 48 to my $a2 and it worked

```
 found:
addi $t4,$t4,4 #selects correct pos for encrypted message
lb $a2, tabChar($t4) #load first byte from input
subi $t4,$t4,4 #reverting pos
addi $a2,$a2,48
sb $a2, outBuf($t0) #store it into outbuff at index pos
addi $t0, $t0, 1 #add index
j linearLoop
```

Comment: You got it. The Ascii code `0x30` (decimal 48) corresponds to "0", `0x31 = "1"`,  `0x32 = "2"`, etc. Out of curiosity, is it possible that you could have put quotes around the numbers in your data section, e.g. `.word   '$', '4'`

Comment: No, on my data section its
 .word  '$', 4